# How to get fields of a class without parent class fields in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get fields of a concrete class (without parent class fields). This is what I tried:

```js
class A {
      constructor() {
          this._a = 1;
      }
  }; 
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._b = 2;
    }
};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new B()));//prints [ '_a', '_b' ]
```

However, I need to get only fields which are declared in `B` class. Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need this? You have range of options for working with data. Anyways, one thing you can do is getting properties of `A` as well and finding the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 2 instances of `A` and `B` and use the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to get the properties of each instance.
after that you use the `filter` method to check if `B`'s properties exist on `A`.

```js
class A {
      constructor() {
          this._a = 1;
      }
  }; 
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this._b = 2;
    }

};


const bproperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new B());

const aproperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new A());

console.log(bproperties.filter(x => !aproperties.includes(x)));
```